# Does the human body have a measurable gravitational field?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, experimental-physics, mass

I am researching communication other than speech or vision.

The human body emits radiation in the form of heat;
As the body has mass, will it  have a gravitational field?

Comment: http://nextbigfuture.com/2016/03/tiny-mems-gravity-sensor-could-detect.html

Answer (score 3):

Yes the human body has a gravitational field, and yes it's large enough to be measured experimentally (see the [Cavendish experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavendish_experiment)).