# Do people have an attractive force?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, everyday-life, estimation, order-of-magnitude

The definition of gravity is this from google:

> "the force that attracts a body toward the center of the earth, or toward any other physical body having mass."

Ok what about the actual physical body of a person? Do they create gravity? If so can this be observed on a small scale? How big does an object have to be before it starts exerting gravity?

Comment: Please consider editing your question to avoid derailing your question with a discussion about obesity. All people, even tiny babies, exert gravitational forces, just like non-living masses. For an experimental approach, read about the Cavendish experiment.

Comment: The reason there is an attractive force between you and the Earth is because there is an attractive force between every individual *atom* in you and every individual *atom* in the Earth. (Or you could think in terms of even smaller masses like protons, neutrons, and electrons.)

Comment: The smallest objects for which I personally have measured gravitational attraction were about a kilogram. We did this in an undergraduate lab in college. The world's record smallest object to be measured is a 2mm gold sphere. [A tiny gold ball is the smallest object to have its gravity measured](https://www.sciencenews.org/article/physics-gravity-measurement-smallest-object-mass-gold-ball)

Comment: Duplicate of [Does the human body have a measurable gravitational field?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/253642/does-the-human-body-have-a-measurable-gravitational-field)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. Everything with mass (Energy) can deform space-time and therefore "attrack" other objects. Yo can read about the Cavendish experiment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Every single object, no matter how big or small has a gravitational force. For it to be measured, it needs to be an amount that a gravimeter can detect. The smallest thing ever measured was a gold ball 2 mm wide with a weight of 90 milligrams.